# removing stop words from corpus in R is too slow

Tags: r, text, analytics, corpus, text-analysis

I have loaded my corpus which includes 16 text files but it has taken about 2 hours to remove stop words from this corpus.
the total size of the corpus is 31Mb. 
Do you know how can I fix this problem?

```
multidocMBTI <- Corpus(DirSource("F:/my master course/Principle of analytics/DATA03"))
multidocMBTI <- tm_map(multidocMBTI, removeWords, stopwords("english"))
```

Comment: Use `quanteda` instead of `tm`. It runs in parallel, with `quanteda_options` you can set the number of threads if you have more than 2 available.

Comment: Thanks for your respond I will try it.